# how to hide sum value that is null in sql?

Tags: mysql, null, sum

### how to remove rows that contained null values?

---

I'm new with sql so, how can I hide rows that contained null values?
I want to hide or perhaps remove the rows with null value in my report so it will only show rows that has some data on it. Any help will be appreciated...

```
SELECT `id`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '1' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END) AS 'annual',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '2' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END)'sick',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '3' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END)'compassionate',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '4' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END)'maternity',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '5' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END)'matrimonial',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND `leave_type` = '7' AND `status`<>'Canceled' AND `s_status`='Approved' THEN `no_days` ELSE NULL END)'unpaid'
 FROM `leave_history`
 GROUP BY `id`
```

---

Here is the Output of my Query

```
id     annual    sick   compassionate  maternity  matrimonial  unpaid
2        20       40      (NULL)         (NULL)      (NULL)     (NULL)
5      (NULL)   (NULL)    (NULL)         (NULL)      (NULL)     (NULL)
11     (NULL)   (NULL)    (NULL)         (NULL)      (NULL)     (NULL)
55     (NULL)   (NULL)    (NULL)         (NULL)      (NULL)     (NULL)
135    1           1      (NULL)         (NULL)      (NULL)     (NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: ohh thank for the edit AbcAeffchen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the IS NULL / IS NOT NULL predicates and the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT id ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '1' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS annual ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '2' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS sick ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '3' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS compassionate ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '4' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS maternity ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '5' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS matrimonial ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25' AND leave_type = '7' AND status<>'Canceled' AND s_status='Approved' THEN no_days ELSE NULL END) AS unpaid
FROM leave_history GROUP BY id
HAVING annual IS NOT NULL AND sick IS NOT NULL ... and so on
```

Comment: actually all the data in my table is not null but somehow it reads all the records in my table and give me null if the condition not meet..

Comment: What do you mean? The HAVING clause is executed after the aggregation. Which rows do you want to filter from the result set? Those with all columns being NULL or those with any column being NULL? For the first case, you have to OR the IS NOT NULL predicates in the HAVING clause.

Comment: thanks a lot moo...i finally understand what u meant...thanks a lot!~ now my code is working...

Comment: Next time, use the SQL documentation. This was a rather easy question.